# Python - Hypnotic turtle using nested for loops and If-else to change the color

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
for x in range(50):

    for l in range(4):
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.forward(L)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(L)
        turtle.right(90)
        L = L+y
```

This code gives me a hypnotic turtle pattern of only one color - red. 
How can I include if/else statements in the outer loop to alter the colors between 'red','blue','brown','black'?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. When do you want to alter colors precisely?

Comment: You could do something like use a dictionary to store a color with a value and change the value every time you complete a loop.  Also, where are you getting color from?  I don't see it anywhere

Comment: to alter color every time it completes one loop ..

Comment: @Michael Platt: I had declared variable color = 'red' . my bad .. didnt add that part of the declaration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something like change between colors you'll want to use modulo math. If you wanted to swap between 4 colors then   `x % 4` will give `0,1,2,3` in that order as it is the remainder when x is divided by 4.  Adding to that a list where each index has a color will have it cycle through those values ex:

```
colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow", "pink"]
for x in range(50):
    color = colors[x%4]

    for l in range(4):
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.forward(L)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(L)
        turtle.right(90)
        L = L+y
```

Comment: true, a list makes more sense here

Comment: Thanks lot for the solution using modulo math. Was wondering if we can achieve the same output using if/else statements in the outer loop ?? for every one iteration of the inner loop ..

Comment: You totally can, using a list is fewer lines of code but absolutely you could.  You could either use a counter so outside establish lines = 0.  Then if 0 then red ... On your last iteration you'd reset the counter.  So for our example and you have 3 colors you'd do:  If lines == 3: color = blue, then set lines = 0  Edit: again this would work it's just not as sleek

Comment: @user8163495 of course you can use `if elif` as a `switch` statement, but why would you?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what you want, but maybe this does what you want.

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'brown', 'black']
for _, color in zip(range(50), itertools.cycle(colors)):
   for i in range(4):
       do_stuff(color)
```

the outer loop can be changed into `itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(colors), 50)` if you don't need iteration counter.

Answer (score 0):

Another hypno-groovy approach:

```
for _ in range(50):

    for color in ['red', 'blue', 'brown', 'black']:

        turtle.pencolor(color)

        for _ in range(2):
            turtle.forward(L)
            turtle.right(90)

        L += y
```

[image]